# Letter q appearing when running program in Python 2.5 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input, python-2.5

The coded line:

```
card_int_rate = raw_input ('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: ')
```

display automatically a letter q at input point that cannot be erased when running the program on the python shell both in Python versions 2.5 and 2.7. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me; this is something entirely local to your system.

Comment: Copy the line as it appears above back into your program.  My guess is a non-displayable character is in there currently, but SO stripped it out.

Comment: The letter q even appears if I write the code line: card_int_rate  = raw_input ().

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have to specify utf-8 encoding in your file. Try putting these two lines at the very top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Why would not having this cause a `q` to appear at input point? I don't see how specifying Unicode handling causes that. As the question comments note, the problem is entirely specific to OP's platform, so I doubt _this_ is going to solve their problem without further elucidation.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why, but whenever I've had weird characters appear when I'm trying to print something to the screen, specifying unicode usually fixed it

Comment: Yes, but OP _isn't_ trying to print to the screen. As for why weird characters appear for _you_ - you're right, it's because Python has no way of knowing what encoding you're using and thus how to represent characters correctly, so specifying Unicode solves that. However, that's not applicable to this problem.